# CSV Import Script stops after a several minutes

Tags: woocommerce, timeout, csv-import

I am writing a woocommerce CSV import script. The CSV file has 1000 rows. In my localhost all 1000 rows are creating products in about 40 minutes. But when I upload that script in Hostgator live server it creates about 200 - 300 rows and stops creating products with no errors. I have set `set_time_limit(0);` but no luck.

It is working fine in localhost but not in live server. So I assume the problem is related to server configuration. Can anybody help me to trace out this problem?

Comment: Assuming that you are on PHP - are you sure `set_timeout` really works? What about the memory-limit?  Did you look at the error-log?

Comment: I am using memory_limit = -1 , max_execution_time = 0 in php.ini

Comment: U need 2 invest more time your questions, if U R really after a good answer. I think you need to completely present your environment

Comment: How does the import actually work? CLI or server? Is the CSV uploaded? -then check your post-max-size and upload-limit. If its executed using CLI check if there is a dedicated php.ini for CLI loaded. Again - check your error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all

> max_input_time and
>   set_time_limit(0)

will only work with VPS or dedicated servers . Instead of that you can follow some rules to your implementation like below

1. First read the whole CSV file .
2. Then grab only 10 entries (rows) or less and make a ajax calls to import in DB
3. Try to call ajax every time with 10 entries and after that echo out something on browser . In this method your script will never timeout .
4. Follow the same method untill the CSV rows are finished .